# CS50 PSET1 Greedy - Assignment error and using modulo ( C )

Tags: c, cs50

I am getting an error when compiling this code. `Z` is the final count of coins needed to make change with aim being to use minimum number of coins. I defined `int Z = 0` near the top. I've tried adding `int z` again and changing type to `f` in print statement but no luck.

Here's the error:

```
error: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type '<dependent type>' [-Werror,-Wformat]
greedy.c:77:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'z'
printf("%i\n", z);
```

Here is my code. I am a beginner so any suggestions or corrections would be welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    //prompt user for amount of change owed

    float f;
    int num; //amount of change

    do
    {
        printf("O hai! How much change is owed?:\n");
        f = get_float();
    }
    while (f < 0);   //verify input is positive

    num = round(f * 100); //rounds float

    //commence making change

    do{

        int c, e, i, j;

        int z = 0;   //z = coins

        if (num % 25 == 0)   // verifies that num is divisible by 25 so only 25c coins necessary
        {
            z = (num/25) + z; // updates final number of 25c coins
        }
        else if (num % 25 > 0)
        {

            i = num / 25;
            j = num % 25;

        }

        else if ((num / 25 < 0) || (num >=10 && num < 25))  //this means that f is less than 25 cents so has to be divided by 10 cent coins
        {

            num = c; 
            c = j + c;  //add remainder of num to the number to start with 
        }

        if (c % 10 == 0) // c is less than 25c but divisible by 10c pieces
        {
            z = (c / 10) + z;   //d is the final number of 10c coins

        }

        else if (c /10 < 1) //this means it's less than 10c
        {
            c = e;  // Then c must be less than 10c 
        }

        else if (e % 5 == 0) // divisible by 5c pieces
        {
            z = (e / 5) + z; // g is the number of 5 cent pieces

        }

        else if (e % 5 < 0) 
        {
        z = (e / 1) + z;  //h is the number of pennies        
        }

    }
    while (num > 0); //num is rounded float

    printf("%i\n", z);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I suggest you should format your code properly with indents.

Then, the cause of error is that `z` is declared inside the block associated to `do` loop and `printf("%i\n", z);` is out of its scope.
To get rid of this error, declare `z` at the place where visible from the `printf()` call -- for example, just before the `do` loop.

Note that declaring `int Z = 0` won't work because identifiers' names are case-sensitive in C.

Answer (score 0):

Like already said, you are declaring z inside the do-while loop, so it's visible only inside the loop.

You should declare it before the loop starts, so you can use it after the loop ends as well. Like this:

```
int z = 0;   //z = coins
do{
***YOUR CODE***
} while();
```